# Why does the R expression "library(sf)" fails when run from another process?

Tags: r, sf, loading, library

I'm using sf and raster packages to manipulate maps. It works perfectly when I run it with Rscript command, and when I run it inside a .sh shell wrapper, too. But when I try to run the script from an Apache server using PHP's exec or proc_open functions, sf library fails to load showing this message.

> Loading required package: sf
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sf’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
> unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/sf/libs/sf.so':
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.20: symbol X509_check_host, version OPENSSL_1.0.2 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference
> Execution halted

I know it is not an error from libmysqlclient or libcrypto because the script works when run from terminal.
Here are the importing lines from my script

```
 require(sp)
 require(raster)
 require(sf)
 require(jsonlite)
 require(RColorBrewer)
```

Here is my PHP code

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/Rscript /opt/lampp/htdocs/proj/script.R {$arg1} {$arg2} {$arg3} {$arg4} &> /opt/lampp/htdocs/proj/cmd.log";
// $cmd = "./shan.sh";
try {
  exec($cmd);
  die();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getTraceAsString();
}
```

And this is the shell wrapper code, it's the same as the PHP code but I wanted to test if wrapping it would change a thing.

```
#!/bin/bash
setsid /usr/bin/Rscript /opt/lampp/htdocs/proj/script.R "arg1" "arg2" "arg3" "arg4" &> /opt/lampp/htdocs/proj/cmd.log
```

This is my Sys.getenv() when I RUN THE SCRIPT FROM TERMINAL

> DISPLAY                 :0
> EDITOR                  vi
> HOME                    /home/clustertic
> LANG                    en_US.UTF-8
> LC_ADDRESS              es_MX.UTF-8
> LC_IDENTIFICATION       es_MX.UTF-8
> LC_MEASUREMENT          es_MX.UTF-8
> LC_MONETARY             es_MX.UTF-8
> LC_NAME                 es_MX.UTF-8
> LC_NUMERIC              es_MX.UTF-8
> LC_PAPER                es_MX.UTF-8
> LC_TELEPHONE            es_MX.UTF-8
> LC_TIME                 es_MX.UTF-8
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH         /usr/lib/R/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/amd64/server
> LN_S                    ln -s
> LOGNAME                 root
> LS_COLORS               rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
> MAIL                    /var/mail/root
> MAKE                    make
> PAGER                   /usr/bin/pager
> PATH                    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
> PWD                     /opt/lampp/htdocs/proj
> R_ARCH
> R_BROWSER               xdg-open
> R_BZIPCMD               /bin/bzip2
> *R_CHECK_COMPILATION_FLAGS_KNOWN*
> -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time
> R_DOC_DIR               /usr/share/R/doc
> R_GZIPCMD               /bin/gzip -n
> R_HOME                  /usr/lib/R
> R_INCLUDE_DIR           /usr/share/R/include
> R_LIBS_SITE             /usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/library
> R_LIBS_USER             ~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1
> R_PAPERSIZE             letter
> R_PAPERSIZE_USER        letter
> R_PDFVIEWER             /usr/bin/xdg-open
> R_PLATFORM              x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
> R_PRINTCMD              /usr/bin/lpr
> R_RD4PDF                times,inconsolata,hyper
> R_SESSION_TMPDIR        /tmp/RtmpgMtj7Q
> R_SHARE_DIR             /usr/share/R/share
> R_STRIP_SHARED_LIB      strip --strip-unneeded
> R_STRIP_STATIC_LIB      strip --strip-debug
> R_SYSTEM_ABI            linux,gcc,gxx,gfortran,gfortran
> R_TEXI2DVICMD           /usr/bin/texi2dvi
> R_UNZIPCMD              /usr/bin/unzip
> R_ZIPCMD                /usr/bin/zip
> SED                     /bin/sed
> SHELL                   /bin/bash
> SHLVL                   1
> SUDO_COMMAND            ./shan.sh
> SUDO_GID                1000
> SUDO_UID                1000
> SUDO_USER               clustertic
> TAR                     /bin/tar
> TERM                    xterm-256color
> USER                    root
> USERNAME                root
> XAUTHORITY              /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority

And this one is my Sys.getenv() when the script IS RAN FROM APACHE

> de                      false
> DISPLAY                 :0
> EDITOR                  vi
> GETTEXT                 /opt/lampp/bin/gettext
> HOME                    /home/clustertic
> LANG                    en_US.UTF-8
> LC_ADDRESS              es_MX.UTF-8
> LC_IDENTIFICATION       es_MX.UTF-8
> LC_MEASUREMENT          es_MX.UTF-8
> LC_MONETARY             es_MX.UTF-8
> LC_NAME                 es_MX.UTF-8
> LC_NUMERIC              es_MX.UTF-8
> LC_PAPER                es_MX.UTF-8
> LC_TELEPHONE            es_MX.UTF-8
> LC_TIME                 es_MX.UTF-8
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH         /usr/lib/R/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/amd64/server:/opt/lampp/lib:/opt/lampp/lib
> LN_S                    ln -s
> LOGNAME                 root
> LS_COLORS               rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
> MAIL                    /var/mail/root
> MAKE                    make
> PAGER                   /usr/bin/pager
> PATH                    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
> PWD                     /opt/lampp/htdocs/atlas
> R_ARCH
> R_BROWSER               xdg-open
> R_BZIPCMD               /bin/bzip2
> *R_CHECK_COMPILATION_FLAGS_KNOWN*
> -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time
> R_DOC_DIR               /usr/share/R/doc
> R_GZIPCMD               /bin/gzip -n
> R_HOME                  /usr/lib/R
> R_INCLUDE_DIR           /usr/share/R/include
> R_LIBS_SITE             /usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/library
> R_LIBS_USER             ~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1
> R_PAPERSIZE             letter
> R_PAPERSIZE_USER        letter
> R_PDFVIEWER             /usr/bin/xdg-open
> R_PLATFORM              x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
> R_PRINTCMD              /usr/bin/lpr
> R_RD4PDF                times,inconsolata,hyper
> R_SESSION_TMPDIR        /tmp/RtmpZq3gik
> R_SHARE_DIR             /usr/share/R/share
> R_STRIP_SHARED_LIB      strip --strip-unneeded
> R_STRIP_STATIC_LIB      strip --strip-debug
> R_SYSTEM_ABI            linux,gcc,gxx,gfortran,gfortran
> R_TEXI2DVICMD           /usr/bin/texi2dvi
> R_UNZIPCMD              /usr/bin/unzip
> R_ZIPCMD                /usr/bin/zip
> SED                     /bin/sed
> SHELL                   /bin/bash
> SHLVL                   1
> SUDO_COMMAND            /opt/lampp/lampp start
> SUDO_GID                1000
> SUDO_UID                1000
> SUDO_USER               clustertic
> TAR                     /bin/tar
> TERM                    xterm-256color
> TEXTDOMAIN              xampp
> USER                    root
> USERNAME                root
> XAMPP_OS                Linux
> XAMPP_ROOT              /opt/lampp
> XAUTHORITY              /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority